# body-parser read json post data node.js express

Tags: json, node.js, express, content-type, body-parser

I'm using `"body-parser": "1.15.0"` and `"express": "4.13.4"`
And I'm trying to get the `json` data from the `body` part of a `http` post request.

This is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
///Set Connection config
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//Body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json(({ type: 'application/*+json', 
                            inflate: false
                        })));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));//Read post info

app.use(function(req, res, next) {

   //Response config
   res.charset = 'utf-8'; 
   res.set({
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   });

   console.log("body: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));

});

// Routing
require('./routes')(app,io);//define routes

//Connect
server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});
```

The problem is that I'm getting `req.body` as `undefined`, I have done some searches and find out that the definition of the `parser` needs to be before the `routes` definition. The `post` request needs to have `"Content-Type" : "application/json"`.

I have that but still getting the `undefined`....

If I use the `app.use(bodyParser.text());` and change the `"Content-Type" : "plain/text"` it works fine, with `"Content-Type" : "x-www-form-urlencoded"` it also works...

But I need to use `"Content-Type" : "application/json"` can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Data send from objective-c

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:method];
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSDictionary* sendInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"test", @"user" , nil];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:sendInfo options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *jsonDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *requestData = [jsonDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];

//Capturing server response
NSError* error;
NSHTTPURLResponse* response;
NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request  returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Comment: how are you sending json to server?

Comment: hi, i'm sending the post from an ios aplication and using the Advanced REST client (chrome plugin) to test, but getting the same result... i have test the headers being send and they have the correct content type

Comment: see my answer and try it, i have answered assuming you client will be sending pure `json`, if so it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, find the problem... but i cannot explain why this happen..
To start reading json bodies i had to change the method:

*app.use(function(req, res, next)*

for this one:

*app.use('/', bodyParser.json(), function(req, res, next)*

And every thing started to work

Comment: can you help me with this, please? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41167585/node-js-unable-to-read-post-json-data-in-my-webhook?noredirect=1#comment69586756_41167585

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing following line in your code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json(({ type: 'application/*+json', 
                            inflate: false
                        })));
```

With following:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: With that change i get an erro 400 bad access (SyntaxError: Unexpected token) the json i'm sending is {"user" : " teste"}