# Node.js unable to read POST JSON data in my webhook

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, post

I have a node.js + Express application. It has a webhook that I have provided to a third party service. The service sends a POST request to my webhook with JSON body which looks something like this:

> {"split_info" : "null", "customerName" : "Merchant Name",
>   "additionalCharges" : "null", "paymentMode":"CC",
>   "hash":"a31ff1b91fd9b8ae9c82f38b02348d21fsdfd86cc828ac9a0acf82050996372cc656de3db0fe3bf9af52b73a182a77787241f3e19ec893391607301b03e70db8",
>   "status" : "Release Payment", "paymentId" : "551731" ,
>   "productInfo":"productInfo", "customerEmail":"test@gmail.com",
>   "customerPhone":"9876543212", "merchantTransactionId":"jnn",
>   "amount":"100.0", "udf2":"null", "notificationId" :"4", "udf1":"null",
>   "udf5":"null", "udf4":"null", "udf3":"null","error_Message":"No
>   Error"}

I am using body-parser module to read POST data. However when I do req.body it gives [object Object], if I do JSON.stringify(req.body), it gives {} i.e. empty. If I try to access the keys in the response like req.body.paymentMode then it gives undefined.

Here is my router code for the webhook: **mywebhook.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/success', function(req, res){

    //this is where I need to strip the JSON request
    //req.body or JSON.stringify(req.body) or anything that works
    //if everything is okay then I send
    res.sendStatus(200);

});

module.exports = router;
```

My **app.js** looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');                               
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var router = express.Router();                                  
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mywebhook = require('./routes/mywebhook');  

var app = express(); 

.
.
.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json


app.use('/callwebhook', mywebhook);

.
.
.
so on
```

Pretty sure I am missing something or doing something wrong, but I am not able to figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the `Content-type` of the request is `application/vnd.api+json`? This seems rather strange to me.

Comment: You are right, when I tested the thrid party webhook using hookbin.com it says the content type is: */*. so do I change the content type in my app.js as  app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: '*/*' }));

Comment: Ok, I changed the type to '*/*' but the req.body is still empty.

Comment: I highly doubt that again. Just `console.log(req.get('Content-Type'));` in your webhook handler and you'll know...

Comment: Ok, so when I print out the content type it gives:  asterisk/asterisk;charset=UTF-8

Comment: This is the link to the thrid party's POST request data: https://github.com/payumoney-india/Webhooks/raw/master/Transaction_POST_Format.pdf

Comment: Then, the right choice for type is `asterisk/asterisk`. Again, this seems rather strange, but less than the last one. The PDF does say they're using `application/json`, but if that's what you're getting from a valid callback it's obviously not what they do.

Comment: Ok, I did change the type: app.use(bodyparser.json({type: asterisk/asterisk})) but I am still not able to read the body. I tested their webhook POST call using hookbin.com and it worked there. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what was going on.

The way the body-parser works is that it will only try to parse a request in which they understand the Content-Type. This is mainly so you can stack them (app.use multiple parser types without conflict) and also because you typically don't want to parse a request that's going to fail (Content-Type: text/html is unlikely to ever get through a JSON.parse, for example).

I ended up getting sent `*/*; charset=UTF-8` which is not even a valid Content-Type header value period. The body-parser module refused to accept it, since that is gibberish. This module does allow you to setup a function that lets you put any custom logic you want to perform the filtering.

I had to put the body parser in my router code just for this webhook case.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var customParser = bodyParser.json({type: function(req) {
    return req.headers['content-type'] === '*/*; charset=UTF-8';
}});

router.post('/success', customParser, function(req, res){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
});
```

@svens thank you for your help.